# Running multiple react-native apps in different ports

Tags: android, react-native, metro-bundler

How to run multiple instances of metro bundler or react-native apps in a single machine ? The default port that the react-native app runs on is 8081.

Comment: Its totally ok to answer your own question, and this sounds like great info to have.  But you should really format this as a question, then answer your own question (and accept the answer when the timer allows in a few days).

Comment: thanks, I can definitely do that .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is the solution, hoping you do not have to go through the same pain.

If you want to run more than one react-native apps in debugging mode, then follow the steps. By default metro bundler run on 8081. So you must change the port for each app to be different.

### Steps

1. First list devices that you are using

   - `adb devices`
     example:
     emulator-5554 device
     emulator-5556 device
2. Running react-native apps on different ports .

   - `react-native run-android --port 8081 --deviceId emulator-5556`
   - `react-native run-android --port 8088 --deviceId emulator-5554`
     ** By default the emulator-5554 will try to run on 8081, and will show error. Do the next step.

- The default port is 8081 so , we do not need to do extra thing after this for emulator-5556.
  Do the next step for emulator-5554

3. Change the server and port number in Dev-settings

- go to dev-setting in react-native app [ Command + M in Mac and Ctrl + M in windows.
  ** Under Debugging section for emulator-5556, in Debug server host & port for device :
- change it to `localhost:8088`
  ** This will change the app to listen to metro-bundler in localhost: 8088 .

Hope this will help you as well, as it wasted my 3 hours just to figure this out.

Comment: this solution is very helpful for me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this question when looking for iOS, you can do this for each app you wish to run on another port:

**Using a port other than 8081**

`npx react-native start --port=8088`

Update your Xcode `ios/__App_Name__.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` file to load the JavaScript bundle from the new port.

For example in the file:

This
`${RCT_METRO_PORT:=8081}`

Changed to this `${RCT_METRO_PORT:=8088}`

Source: https://reactnative.dev/docs/troubleshooting#port-already-in-use