# react-native run-android with port and device option always creates release build

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

I am trying to run two react-native apps on two separate emulators by following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58030350/10910772). I run the following command:

```
npx react-native run-android --port 8081 --deviceId emulator-5556
```

However, instead of generating a debug build, the system tries to create a release build. Interestingly, if I run `npx react-native run-android`without any extra options, I get a debug build.

I tried to force a debug build by adding `--variant=debug` to the command and also setting `bundleInDebug: false` in `app/build.gradle` but it didn't help.

Is there a way to run a debug build in this situation?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I am experiencing this same issue since upgrading a RN project.